# Unable to delete tax rate

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, delete

Whenever I try to delete a tax rate, I get below error message.

```
Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule
```

I checked there is no tax rule in admin. I have deleted all tax rules.

**UPDATE**

I have found some posts asking to delete data from **tax_calulation** table manually. Is it correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete all Tax Rates then
Just `truncate` `tax_calculation_rate` table via php my admin, Please keep backup of this table before perform this query.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to delete the table. This is not an error, but rather normal behavior. This is because the tax rate is being used. To be able to remove the tax rate:

1. Go to: Admin > Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules.
2. Find the rule that is using this tax rate.
3. Either delete that rule, or change the tax rate that rule uses.
4. Go aback to the Tax Rates and you will be able to delete it.

Comment: There are no rules at Admin > Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteTaxRate() {

try {

    foreach (Mage::getModel('tax/calculation_rate')->getcollection() as $rate) {
        echo 'Tax Rate Deleted : '.$rate->getId();
        $rate->delete();
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Delete tax rate failed '.PHP_EOL;
    echo $e->getMessage();
}}
```

Please use the above script.